# Difference function in prolog for multisets

Tags: prolog

I want to calculate the difference between two lists - 
Here is my attempt at it

```
difference(X, [], X).
difference(H,[S|T],H):-
 del(S, H, H2),
 difference(H2, T, H2).

del(Y,[Y],[]).
del(X,[X|L1],L1).
del(X,[Y|L],[Y|L1]):-del(X,L,L1).
```

But when I call it  `difference([a,a,b,b,b,c,d,d],[b,b,c,c,c,d,d,e],X). false.` It returns false instead of giving the difference. 
For this case the answer should be `{a, a, b}`

Comment: One hint: look at the first and last argument of difference/3! They are always the same.

Comment: What about the fact that the second argument contains two extra 'c's and an 'e'? Shouldn't the result be `[a, a, b, c, c, e]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
difference(A, [], A).
difference(A, [X|C], D) :- del(X, A, B), difference(B, C, D).

del(_, [], []).
del(X, [X|B], B).
del(X, [Y|B], [Y|C]) :- X \= Y, del(X, B, C).
```

Running example:

```
?- difference([a,a,b,b,b,c,d,d],[b,b,c,c,c,d,d,e],X).
X = [a, a, b] ;
false.
```